# Create Menu HTML from Java ArrayList

Tags: java, html, json, arraylist

I have an arraylist in Java ArrayList`[Consultas.ControldeInformes, Consultas.SaldoMora, Consultas.ReporteMensual, Mantenimientos.Agregar, Mantenimientos.Editar, Mantenimientos.Actualizar]`

I would like to convert the arraylist to place it as menus and submenus in HTML, how to iterate the array to be of this structure:

```
Menu: Consultas
Submenus: ControldeInformes,SaldoMora,ReporteMensual

Menu: Mantenimientos
Submenus: Agregar,Editar,Actualizar
```

How to separate or split the arraylist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write a code to create a map with your requirements:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<> (Arrays.asList(
          "Consultas.ControldeInformes", "Consultas.SaldoMora", 
          "Consultas.ReporteMensual", "Mantenimientos.Agregar", 
          "Mantenimientos.Editar", "Mantenimientos.Actualizar"

        ));
    System.out.print(mapInput(exampleList).toString());
  }

 private static Map<String,List<String>> mapInput(List<String> input) {

    Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();

    input.stream()
      .map(x->getMenu(x))
      .distinct()
      .forEach(x->map.put(x, new ArrayList<>()));

    for (String item : input) {
      List<String> subMenus = map.get(getMenu(item));
      subMenus.add(getSubMenu(item));

      map.put(getMenu(item), subMenus);
    }

    return map;
  }

  private static String getMenu(String item){
    return item.split("\\.")[0];
  }

  private static String getSubMenu(String item){
    return item.split("\\.")[1];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, it's just what I needed. Now, how can I do to show that in a Menu and submenus on a jsp page? `{Consultas=[ControldeInformes, SaldoMora, ReporteMensual], Mantenimientos=[Agregar, Editar, Actualizar]}`